# URL not passing parameters to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing

I am using SSRS 2008.

This is my URL:

```
http://mybox/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/BI/PlayerProfiler+v3.0&id=548127&SP=FS
```

In my report I have 2 parameters the ID and the SP.

The ID is a plain text box and the SP is a drop down.
[image]

For some reason the ID does populate the text box but the SP does not want to get selected with the way I am passing the URL.

Why not?? The display value and the real value is FS....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! There was a space next to my actual value of the SP parameter. My fault and I do apologize! Thus the value was not "FS" it was "FS ".....