# Download Report and attach to email

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I would like to ask if anyone knows the thing that i want to do:

I have a report in microsoft report server that's waiting for a parameter (person_id) to make the fulfill.

I need to send an email with the report of each person_id. I need to run a function that runs my report called per_permissions.rdl download it and attached the file to send it by email. Example in vb.net code

```
strSql = "SELECT per_id,per_email FROM person"
dt_person = getDataTable(strSql)

For each dr_person As DataRow in dt_persona.Rows
 attached_file = mysticFunction(dr_person("per_id"))
 ...
Next

Public Shared Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _URL As String, ByVal _SaveAs As String)
  Try 
    Dim _WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    _WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAs) 
  Catch _Exception As Exception 
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString()) 
  End Try 
End Sub
```

Comment: for each person in the loop you should save a report as .pdf to a temporary path and then attach it to your email using that path.

Comment: exactly but the problem is that i dont know how to do that...

Comment: what is the mysticFunction doing? are you sure you're using ms reporting services? or is it a local report? show more code please

Comment: i need to do it.

what i have for now is a function called downloadFile

Public Shared Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _URL As String, ByVal _SaveAs As String)
        Try
            Dim _WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
            _WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAs)
        Catch _Exception As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: but i dont know how to make a page that run my report url and directly download it

Comment: i'm a php coder, i know that i can make .php with header and the ocntent will be downloaded but i dont know how to make it in .aspx pages

Comment: after the DownloadFile function is completed you should be able to find that file at the specified url. is it working?

Comment: are you sure you're creating the correct url with your person parameter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633122/url-not-passing-parameters-to-ssrs-report?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fairly simple. Using the `ReportExecutionService.Render` method you can render the report however you want. We've used this to run reports and attach them to emails automatically.

The MSDN site [has some code to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx).

To add a reference to the report execution web service, right-click `References`, select `Add Service Reference...` and add a reference to the web service that will look something like:

```
http://MyReportServer/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx
```

You will also need the report service web service, which is:

```
http://MyReportServer/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx
```

Comment: i can set with this method like an auto download??
ex: auto-download:true so i can make it in a loop to download an attach the report into an email

Comment: Yes, you can loop this and run the report many times and attach it to emails. Instead of trying to run it with a URL like you are doing, you should use the `ReportExecutionService` object to render the report in code, which will return a `Byte()` that you can turn into a `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` or whatever, turn that into an attachment, add it to an email and send it.

Comment: i found several exmaples but seems of newbie but i cant find the dll to add to using ReporService class.... I installed the sql server to look for the libraries but nothing i cant find them to use ReportinService in my code :S

Comment: They aren't DLLs, they are web services - I have added how to add them to my answer.