# How to make SSRS report loop through and email every company?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Hi I have built a view that shows all expired licenses for super admin view as a whole.I want to make an SSRS report that will kick off every day and send an email expired licenses for all the companies in my table essentially a loop.

Any resource for me to tackle this step? this is my first time using SSRS and I have the super admin report view working , I can technically make that into a subscription auto email service but it would show all companies and i just want each company to get their own individual report instead of building a new report for each company.

- Company `Companyid` `Company name`
- resource `resourceid` `companyid` `companyid`
- Qualifications `qualificationsid` `resourceid` `licensenumber` `expirationdate`

Comment: If this case in my hand, I probably would create a stored procedure, send email to each company through the loop, set message body as HTML format. No need SSRS.

Comment: If you are using Enterprise Edition of SSRS then you could use a [data driven subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-data-driven-subscription-ssrs-tutorial).

Comment: You can also write a program to [render the report in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492282/download-report-and-attach-to-email/25497240#25497240). Then you can do whatever you want with the result - i.e.attach to an email.